# set padding on all buttons in app xamarinforms at once

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have designed a whole app in xamarinforms, I want to add left and right padding to 10 points on all buttons in the app, is there a way to do it using App.xaml or any other way where I change the padding of the button for iOS platform only ?

Comment: Padding applies to layout elements, not individual elements like Button.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding

Answer (score 0):

Check these two ms docs:

1. [global style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application) (you can still override the margin/padding on specific pages)
2. [XAML markup for platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/consuming#onplatform-markup-extension)

And this is a sample for your App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style ApplyToDerivedTypes="True" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{x:OnPlatform iOS='10,0', Android='0'}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```